# Get image from XML url and load into UITableView

Tags: iphone, xml, uitableview

I ran into this problem and I would try to solve it.
in the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

I wrote:

```
NSMutableString *urlXML = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[elencoFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"img"]];
NSMutableData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlXML]];
NSLog(@"imgdata: %@",imageData);
```

the xml is written as:

```
<img>http://site/blu.png</img>
```

but the problem is that "urlXML" it responds with URL that is inside the XML tag
but "imageData", it responds to the log with "(null) ".

what I would do is put inside of my UITableView an image for each row.
where am I wrong?

Comment: @Filippo make sure your urlXML string does not contain the <img></img> XML tags. You can also use `initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`, pass in a NSError reference and then check the returned error.

Comment: the NSLog from urlXML is a simple URL without any <tag>

Comment: @Filippo Have you tried `initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`?

Comment: no, may u post me the code, I'm not very handy and I don't know how to initialize the string

Comment: NSError *error = nil; NSMutableData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlXML] options:0 error:&error];
 if (error) {
  NSLog(@"error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
 }

Comment: SIGABRT error on the NSMutData row  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]: nil URL argument'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: @Filippo that crash looks like you forgot to initialize your urlXML string. You can use the same first line of your code as long as it returns a valid url.

Comment: here we are,  error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x4c469e0 {NSURL=}, {
    NSURL = "";

Comment: @Filippo urlXML does not contain what you expect. Try replacing that first line with NSString *urlXML = @"site/blu.png"; (with a valid URL)  and you will be able to initialize imgData

Comment: I had the same mistake by entering the link, how strange! the only thing that makes me think, is that the method is invoked as many times as the tags in XML. and the example I have now is 4 imgs

Comment: @Filippo check my answer, maybe your url contains characters that need to be escaped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try trimming and escaping your urlXML string like this:

```
// Assuming this returns a string with a valid URL (taken from question)
NSString *urlXML = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[elencoFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"img"]];
// reading @Filippo's comments looks like the string returned contains trailing tabs and line breaks, let's trim it
NSString *trimmed = [urlXML stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[trimmed stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

Comment: error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x4e33e80 {NSURL=http://site/green.png%09%09%0A%09%0A%09}, {
    NSURL = "http://site/green.png%09%09%0A%09%0A%09";   i got this error now! where those "%.." come out?

Comment: @Filippo those "%..." came from escaping the string. Are you sure your URL is valid? You should be able to paste your URL in your browser and see the image.

Comment: sure if i paste the url into a browser i see my png, of course without all that %09. the link inside xml is <img>http://site.com/image.png</img> as i wrote in my question

Comment: @Filippo "the link inside xml is <img>site.com/image.png</img>"... does the urlXML string contain the <img></img> tags? It should not contain those.

Comment: no it does not contain the tag, writing this line:
[elencoFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"img"]
from what I understand, I just extrapolates <img> tag inside, but from what I think the% is my problem, because if I make the log urlXML, it gives me back my link with in more spaces

Comment: @Filippo I edited the answer so you can try with a "test" string. Give it a try.

Comment: @Filippo All those %09 are tabs and %0A are line breaks and those are responsible for the error. You need to trim the string. See my edited answer

Comment: thanks a lot friend. now it works fine using both trimmed my xml to google!! thanks =)